# Saving data to db from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

How can i save a javascript variable into MYSQL database? In particular i want to save a score of a game, when it ends. See the code below:

```
function lastScore(num){
    document.getElementById('lastscore').textContent = num;
}


function saveScore(){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","saveScore.php?s="+player.score,false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    document.getElementById("endgame").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
include('server.php');

$s =  $_GET['s'];
$db = mysqli_connect( ...MY DATA...);

$query = "INSERT INTO scores (name, score) VALUES ('$username' , '$s')";
mysqli_query($db, $query);
?>
```

Can you tell me what's wrong? what should i do to be able to insert `player.score` as argument into MYSQL database? Thanks

Comment: I don't see where do you pass value to 'player.score' variable.

Comment: in xmlhttp.open( ... ) isn't it @sskoko ?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: You are trying to pass variable player.score, but you never assigned any value to that variable.

Comment: No error message when this code should trigger @S.Walker

Comment: @sskoko i assign value to it in other part of my js which is bigger than what i've posted here

Comment: But you never pass it to saveScore function.

Comment: passing it as argument i get this error in chrome console: `[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.` which is correspondant to the xmlhttp.open line

Comment: If you are not in a protected environment, this code is subject to sql injection.  Also, the response  to a send is an async by default. I don't see where you have taken that into account.

Comment: can you give me some sample code to realize it? i'm not interested into security at the moment